# Bootstrap modal - background issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm having problems with the background of a bootstrap modal. The modal itself works fine, but the background is not grayed out, see image below.

[image]

The code for the modal is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="issuesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#0066b2;color:#FFFFFF">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 col-form-label">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 form-text">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 col-form-label">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 form-text">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: probably you trying to wrap the modal inside and absolute position div , can you post the css ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. I grabbed your HTML and it seems to work .(see my answer for a running example) - there must be something else at play. Can you provide us with a [mcve] that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif you're right, there's an outer div with absolute position. I can't change that though, is there any way around it?

The css for the div:

div#app {
  background-color: #ededee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; }

Comment: @Gonzalo you need to change it , try to wrap the modal inside a div that dosent have an absolute position

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue, I used your HTML and it seems to work

**Note to others**
I only added this answer to show the OP his HTML works - I will remove the answer once OP posts a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#issuesModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="issuesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#0066b2;color:#FFFFFF">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 col-form-label">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 form-text">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 col-form-label">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 form-text">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: he is using an absolute position that wrap the modal

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I see... thx - let's wait for the OP to provide us with more CSS/HTML then